# Multiple lines in detail text label of table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to have multiple lines in a cell's detailTextLabel but with discrete information on each line. In order to get multiple lines in the detailTextLabel I would use

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

But I am looking to have specific text on each line. I know swift doesn't have a line break so I believe it would have to look like this:

```
 cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Line 1" +
                        "Line 2" +
                        "Line 3" +
                        "Line 4" +
                        "Line 5"
```

But this returns Line1Line2Line3Line4Line5 in the detailsTextLabel.

I can successfully have multiple lines by putting in a super long string and have it wrap down to multiple lines.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Or just not possible?

Comment: try "Line 1" + "\n" + "Line 2" + "\n" . . .

Comment: @Shoaib that works wonderfully, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Shoaib all you have to do is implement "\n" into the string

```
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Line 1" + "\n" + "Line 2" + "\n" + "Line 3" + "\n" + "Line 4" + "\n" + "Line 5"
```

Comment: Note that you dont even need to set the `lineBreadMode` for this to work.

Comment: You can do it better these days. checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602257/5623035)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiline string format like:

```
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = """
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
"""
```

---

## Trick

If you want  to add something like between multiple items (Like @Tamarisk answer) you can get help from an array like:

```
[
    "Line 1",
    "Line 2",
    "Line 3",
    "Line 4",
    "Line 5",
].joined(separator: "\n")
```